# c++ irc client async read & write

Tags: c++, client, winsock, irc

Im starting to make my own irc bot in c++ using winsock. My first version of bot works very simple using blocking mode of socket. It simple reading line by line and write it on screen. Thats all what it should done.

now i want to make a litle bit clever bot with full communication. but i don't know, how to perform it. I tried download some open source irc client to see how the "asynchronous communication is done", but the open source irc clients are large and found there some valuable informations takes lot of time.

How is done irc asynchronous communication in irc clients? is possible to done it without multithreading and overlapped I/O? Which technique is best to perform async communication in c++ winsock?

Answer (score 0):

The most flexible way on Windows is to use completion ports. This [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302334.aspx) on Winsock and completion ports should get you started.

Comment: is there exist any easier way?

Comment: Asynchronous IO is never easy..!

Comment: Use a language that has better abstraction of such things. With some languages asynchronous IO is very easy.